# Unable to submit an HTTPS post with Java

Tags: java-8, tls1.2

I am writing some tools (only meant to be used in a development environment) where I'm trying to automate the submission of messages to a HTTP Post.  My method (below) `sendByHTTPSNaive()` uses a naive implementation of `javax.net.ssl.TrustManager` in order to accept any certificates.  (Again, this is for development testing.)  I'm getting a `401` unauthorized code back. Below is my method and the debug output of the TLS handshake I believe.  The project network people tell me I'm only facing an xml gateway which the naive TrustManager should get through, but have assured me there is no other authentication.  I've run out of ideas of how to debug this issue if it's some TLS thing, or is there in fact another authentication layer besides the xml gateway?

```
public String sendByHTTPSNaive(String destinationURI,
                                String msgBodyContent) {

    String result = "no response";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(destinationURI);
        // URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // specify that we will send output and accept input
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000); // long timeout, but not infinite
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);

        NoopHostnameVerifier HOSTNAME_VERIFIER = new NoopHostnameVerifier();
        TrustManager[] TRUST_MANAGER = { new NaiveTrustManager() };
        if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(new KeyManager[0], TRUST_MANAGER,
                                            new SecureRandom());
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
            ((HttpsURLConnection) con).setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
            ((HttpsURLConnection) con).setHostnameVerifier(HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        }

        // tell the web server what we are sending
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        con.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(msgBodyContent);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        // reading the response
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        char[] cbuf = new char[2048];
        int num;

        while (-1 != (num = reader.read(cbuf))) {
            buf.append(cbuf, 0, num);
        }

        result = buf.toString();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    return result;
}
```

debug output using the flag -Djavax.net.debug=all

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Una
uthorized..Serve
r: Apache-Coyote
/1.1..WWW-Authen
ticate: Basic re
alm="L7SSGBasicR
ealm"..L7-Policy
-URL: https://ab
cdefghi.jklmno.c
om:443/ssg/polic
y/disco?serviceo
id=20938758..Con
tent-Length: 23.
.Date: Thu, 28 A
pr 2016 16:00:56
GMT....Authenti
cation RequiredC
..._.2..5\"B....
:...............
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TLS is working fine, the error is coming from HTTP. You need to provide authentication information along with the request - specifically an [Authorization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) header. The response contains a 'WWW-Authenticate' header - which is challenging the client to provide credentials. The client is supposed to repeat the request with an appropriate 'Authorization' header.